# SQL SELECT WHERE value IN ('Huge list of Values')

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2005

Note: C# 3.5 application calling a SQL Server 2005 DB on a remote server.

I'm developing a two step process.

1) I search a Windows Indexing Service for a list of files that contain a given word, such as "Bob".

2) I then need to retrieve a list of rows from a DOCUMENT table in a SQL DB by passing in the list of filenames from the Indexing Service.

At the moment I retrieve a list from the indexing service AND all rows from the DOCUMENT table, then filter them in code. This isn't practical as there are 10,000+ documents and the database is through a firewall.

I considered creating a query such as:

SELECT DocName FROM Documents WHERE DocName IN ({list of files from indexing service})

...but given the list of files could be thousands it won't work.

So, what's the best thing I can do? I don't want to query the DB for all 10,000+ rows and pass them back over the firewall (takes 10 minutes). I somehow need to pass in the list of filenames retrieved from the indexing service.

How would linq work in this scenario?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: perhaps you can make a copy of the files in the indexing service into a database table, for example every night? Then you could do with a simple JOIN on the two tables. I think you should get all data together before you can query it, now you get everything together at the client which seems cumbersome.

Comment: short answer: insert the names from the indexing service into a temporary table, join the document table and temporary table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had SQL Server 2008, you could use [Table Valued Parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html), but for 2005, there's nothing quite as elegant.

The simplest solution I can think of is:

- Create a table in the database
- Bulk Insert the results of your Indexing Service into the table
- Join your query to this table to filter the results
- Retrieve the filered results

It's not a great solution, but I don't know that a great solution exists - that's why TVPs were created.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate different solutions for this kind of "massive" operation, may be not necessary to use linq. For example, try to implement a stored procedure on SQL Server, that receives in input the list of file name and returns the list of documents.

Answer (score 0):

I opted for a solution similar to what Bazzz mentioned.

I've set up a nightly operation to copy the required fields from the database and set meta tags on the document files (PDFs). The meta data can then be used in the Indexing Service ;o)

This has proved to be a good solution for this instance, but otherwise what Hallainzil said would've been the best option albeit painful on Sql Server 2005.